# Can I populate a table with just one object from an NSArray? How?

Tags: iphone, object, nsarray

I have a table that is populated by an NSArray `mcData` in my AppDelegate implementation file. I want to create a detail view with a grouped table that pulls its data from that same array. However, I can't seem to figure out a way to use a single object with multiple properties to fill a table. Any ideas, or should I take a different approach?

Thanks!

Comment: Question is not clear for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can simple use the same array.
In the detailed you just retain it `@property (nonatomic,retain) NSArray* mcData;`
In the .m file synthesize it and use it as a datasource for the tableView.
Also, don't forget to release it once you are done with the view

Answer (score 0):

You want to map the row index to the property of your object (i.e. 0 = "name", 1 = "zipcode", 2 = "yadayada", etc). Make sense? Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: Find an example of how to implement a table view. In your implementation of the UITableViewDataSource protocol, in its cellFor... method, do something like this: ... if (indexPath.row == 0) cell.textView.text = myobject.name; else if ...   etc